# Most effective UPDATE procedure for multiple tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Example / case:

- `Table_1`: all Soldiers `[fullname, date of birth, ...]`
- `Table_2`: all possible navy ranks `[Seaman, ..., Fleet Admiral]`

Task: Update Soldiers(Pedro A, ..., Alberto Z) from (current rank) Commander to (new rank) Captain

What's the most effective way to perform this?

Comment: So where is the rank of the soldier stored? You didn't mention any column that references the `rank` table.

Comment: `Name(Soldier) = Table_1,

Rank(Soldier) = Table_2
`

Column "name" in Table_1 Soldier
Column "rank" in Table_2 Rank

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: You can do a join while updating but is there any relationship b/w the tables present?

Comment: You're looking for `UPDATE ... FROM ...` by the sounds, but there's not enough detail in this question to be specific.

Comment: Yes, there is a `rank_id` column in `Table_2` and `rank_id` is also a colums in `Table_1`

Answer (score 1):

Use more decritive table names: `soldiers` instead of `Table_1` and `ranks` instead of `Table_2`.

Table with ranks should have id for each rank. Name it `rank_id`. Such `rank_id` may by *1* for *Seaman* and *100* for *Fleet Admiral*. PostgreSQL has `SERIAL` type for such key columns and this should be type of `rank_id`.

In `soldiers` table put column with `rank_id` which will point to record in `ranks` table.

Then you can promote soldiers:

```
UPDATE soldiers SET rank_id=(SELECT rank_id FROM ranks WHERE rank_name='Commander') WHERE rank_id=(SELECT rank_id FROM ranks WHERE rank_name='Captain')
```

Comment: "Table_1" is just for illustration ;) not a "real" table_name.

Comment: thx @Michal Niklas. Thats the right direction ;)

Precise: At the end there will be an external file (.txt, .csv or .xls) with the current names and ranks.
I'm heading for a script that runs something like a ```diff -y``` ;)
identifies the related soldiers and corrects the ranks in the DB.
(And shifts the unnamed soldiers to the "Ex" or "tbd"-Rank.)